# Is this function a characteristic function for some random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, characteristic-functions

I have the following function:

$f(t) = \begin{cases}
0, |t| > 2 \\
1, |t| < 1 \\
2 - |t|, 1 \leqslant |t| \leqslant 2.
\end{cases}$

And I need to check whether it is a characteristic function.

I have checked basic properties ($f(0) = 1$, $|f(t)| \leqslant 1$, and it probably is uniformly continuous? I'm not that well-versed with this one). I don't know how to proceed from there. Either there's some obvious random variable with this characteristic function (if so, then how do I find such random variable, is there some sort of an algorithm? I can't just guess) or I forgot about some important property or maybe made a mistake.

Comment: What about $f(-t)=f(t)$?

Comment: @IvanNeretin well, this one does seem to be true? As there's $|t|$ here; also, I think the property used the conjugate of $f(t)$? Anyway, I thought it was true for this function.

Comment: Of course it's true; I didn't notice the modulo bars around $t$. Well, then take an inverse Fourier transform of it and see whether it makes a valid probability distribution. If it does, then $f$ is a characteristic function all right.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $f$ is the characteristic function of some r.v $X$.

$f$ is $\mathcal C^\infty$ on a neighborhood of $0$, and $f'(0)=f''(0)$. So $E(X)=E(X^2)=0$, hence $X=0$ a.s.

But the characteristic function of the constant $0$ is not $f$, so $f$ is not a characteristic function.